# Why DHCP client doesn't issue a DHCPREQUEST as it has received a DHCPOFFER?

Tags: dhcp

In GNS3 (and using Cisco routers), I've created four subnetworks like the following:

[image: GNS3 DHCP Relay]

The goal is to set up a DHCP server on router `R1` and a DHCP relay agent on router `R2` in order to make it available to `subnet2` and `subnet3`(For the current question, I'm focusing only on `subnet1` and `subnet2`, specifically `PC1` and `PC2`).

After configuring every interface of each router for their IP addresses, I've set up DHCP address pools namely, `subnet1`, `subnet2`, and `subnet3` on router `R1` as shown in the scenario above. On router `R1`, I've also defined a route to `subnet2` using the following commands:

`R1(config)#ip route 20.20.2.0 255.255.255.224 1.12.21.2
 R2(config)#end`

On router `R2`, I've defined a DHCP relay agent on interface `f0/0` using the following:

`R2(config)#int f0/0
 R2(config-if)#ip helper-address 1.12.21.1
 R2(config)#end`

For router `R1`, the output for `show running-config` is:

```
R1#sho running-config
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 1541 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R1
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
no ip dhcp use vrf connected
ip dhcp excluded-address 10.10.1.32 10.10.1.62
ip dhcp excluded-address 20.20.2.16 20.20.2.30
ip dhcp excluded-address 30.30.3.8 30.30.3.14
!
ip dhcp pool subnet1
   network 10.10.1.0 255.255.255.192
   default-router 10.10.1.1
   dns-server 10.10.1.2
   lease 0 2
!
ip dhcp pool subnet2
   network 20.20.2.0 255.255.255.224
   default-router 20.20.2.1
   dns-server 10.10.1.2
   lease 0 0 30
!
ip dhcp pool subnet3
   network 30.30.3.0 255.255.255.240
   default-router 30.30.3.1
   dns-server 10.10.1.2
!
!
no ip domain lookup
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.10.1.1 255.255.255.192
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip address 1.12.21.1 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
ip route 20.20.2.0 255.255.255.224 1.12.21.2
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

For router `R2`, the output for `show ruuning-config` is:

```
    Building configuration...

Current configuration : 998 bytes
!
version 12.4
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname R2
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no aaa new-model
memory-size iomem 5
no ip icmp rate-limit unreachable
ip cef
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
ip tcp synwait-time 5
!
!
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 20.20.2.1 255.255.255.224
 ip helper-address 1.12.21.1
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Serial0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
 clock rate 2000000
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 30.30.3.1 255.255.255.240
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet1/0
 ip address 1.12.21.2 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
!
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
no cdp log mismatch duplex
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line aux 0
 exec-timeout 0 0
 privilege level 15
 logging synchronous
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
end
```

Below is the configuration for switch `SW1` and it's also the same for `SW2` and `SW3`:

[image: SW1-configuration]

For `PC1`, using the command `ip dhcp`, brings back its IP address along with its mask and so on. But on `PC2`, there's a problem. When I try `PC2>ip dhcp` the result is:

`DDDO
 Can't find DHCP server`

I've also used Wireshark on links `R2 to R1` and `SW2 and PC2` and you can see below that two `DHCPOFFER` messages are sent to `PC2` on link `SW2 to PC2`, but no `DHCPREQUEST` is sent back.

[image: R2 to R1 wireshark]

[image: SW2 to PC2]

Where am I wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the network device configurations. We cannot simply guess where you may have gone wrong.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for your comment. I've edited my question. Please tell me if I should add more information to my question.

Comment: Simply perform a `show running-config` command on each router and switch, and paste the results into the question.

Comment: @RonMaupin I just added the required output. I hope this time it works.